# How to change wrong initial directory when open VSC terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh, macos-catalina

I usualy use zsh in VSC. My default shell is zsh. When I open terminal, the initial directory is '~/path/to/workspace'. But after I updated MacOS to Catalina beta, the directory became '/System/Volumes/Data/Users/myusername/workspace'. I want the same behavior as before. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the many changes coming to Catalina. See the following article, item #2:

https://www.sentinelone.com/blog/7-big-security-surprises-coming-to-macos-10-15-catalina/

I am trying to figure out how to use this new location correctly. I'm hoping in a future beta update this will become more transparent.

It appears to be an issue with how macOS is now reporting the selected directory back to apps, including the `/System/Volumes/Data/Users` prefix, to which the `/Users` directory seems to be linked through the filesystem (but not via mounts). However, the native apps are handling this prefix in that they are stripping it away, making it look as if nothing changed, while the 3rd-party apps aren't handling it well yet.

Or perhaps its an inconsistency with how macOS is dealing with these two locations for the `Users` directory, and it's a bug that will be worked out before Catalina launches. I'm fairly certain, that either way, it will be worked out over the coming weeks or months.

**Update** This seems to now display correctly after upgrading to macOS Catalina Beta 3.**